# Algebraic extension over the field of algebraic reals

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

> Let $L$ be the field of algebraic *real* numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K$ be a non-trivial algebraic field extension over $L$ in the field of complex numbers. Does it follows that $K$ coincides with the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

In the famous math problem source "Problems and solutions in mathematics" published by World Scientific, we can see the following problem.

*Problem 1411: (a) Suppose you are given a field $L$, $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq L \subseteq \mathbb{C}$, such that $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is algebraic and every finite field extension of $K/L$, $K \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is of even degree. Show that every finite field extension of $L$ must in fact have degree equal to a power of $2$. (b) Show that such a field $L$ actually exists.*

Then question 1411(a) can be easily resolved by considering arbitrary finite Galois extension of $L$ and applying Sylow theorem to make use of Sylow subgruop of degree power of $2$ of the Galois group. For the question (b), the author of the book solved with the choice $L$ to be the field of all algebraic real numbers to conclude that every finite algebraic extension over $L$ is of degree power of $2$.

My question is that is there any algebraic extension of $L$ other than itself and the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$.

PS: It would be nice if the field $L$ with the property in 1411(a) is unique.

Comment: Fix an embedding $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}\to \Bbb{C}$ then $L=\overline{\Bbb{Q}}\cap \Bbb{R}$ is the subfield of $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}$ fixed by the complex conjugaison thus  $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}= L(\beta)$ for any $\beta \in \overline{\Bbb{Q}}-L$

Comment: @reuns I agree. So the conclusion that any algebraic extension of $L$ is of degree power of $2$ is, although, not wrong, however, not complete since the degree is actually $2$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. About the problem 411 : if $K/L$ is Galois of degree $2^n (2m+1)$ then let $H$ be the subset of $G=Gal(L/K)$ of elements of order $| 2$, it is a subgroup because elements of order 2 commute, and it is a normal subgroup, thus $K^H/L$ is Galois of degree $2^{n-|H|}(2m+1)$, repeat with $K^H/L$ until we get $n=0$. In characteristic $p$ there are the non-separable extensions, but it is not a problem because $K^G/L$ is purely inseparable of degree a power of $p$ so in both case $p$ odd or $p$ even we get the result.